# C++ Templates : define an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this template

```
template <class T, int size=0> class GPr
```

and I want to declare an array for example int [5], which requires to specify the size for example 5. If I write :

```
GPr<int, 5> ap;
```

does this mean that I have int[5] or I need also to modify the place of int:

```
GPr<new int[5], 5> app;
```

??
or

```
GPr<double, 5> pda = new double[5];
```

??

Comment: If your class implementation is correct, `GPr<int, 5> ap; ` should be equivalent to `int ap [5]`.

Comment: I suggest you use `size_t` for array size template parameters.

Comment: Check the chapter on template introduction in whatever book you are using. `T` and `size` will appear amongst your class's member variables and functions.

Comment: What about `std::array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is dependent on you class implementation. You can access using the GPr ap;  and GPr app;  to create the array of template object.